# Angular.js UI-Router Children Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui-router library (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I'm having a bit of confusion around nested views/routes.

#### Here is how I've configured the routes:

```
$stateProvider.state( 'networks', {
  url: '/networks',
  access: accessLevels.admin,
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'NetworksCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'networks/networks.tpl.html'
} )
  .state( 'networks.list', {
    url: '',
    access: accessLevels.admin,
    template: '<h4><i class="icon-chevron-sign-left icon-large"></i> Please select a network from the left</h4>'
  } )
  .state( 'networks.detail', {
    url: '/{networkId}',
    access: accessLevels.admin,
    controller: 'NetworkDetailCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'networks/networkDetail.tpl.html'
  } )
  .state( 'networks.detail.show', {
    url: '/show/{showCode}',
    access: accessLevels.admin,
    views: {
      '@': { // Override the main view, unfortunately this will break the scope so the network info will be requested again
        controller: 'NetworkShowCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'networks/networkShowDetail.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

When you access `/networks` you are presented with a list of networks on the left of the page (similar to the ui-router example here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts).  Clicking on one of the network names displays the details route on the right of the page, which contains a list of clickable `shows`.

However, the part that I'm confused about is what if I wanted the `networks.detail.show` page to actually exist on it's own full-page and maintain scope of the parent `network.details`?  The only way I was able to come up with getting around that is on the `networks.detail.show` route, where you can see I've overridden it to use the main view (which is killing the scope).

I feel like I'm looking at this the wrong way, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time,

-Ryan S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either have to:

1. Add an additional abstract state at the top level that has a template of `'<ui-view/>` and also a controller with all the scope items you need. So you'd essentially be moving the important shared scope items be a part of this top level state instead of `networks.details`. Then set `networks.details.show` to populate this new state's view, e.g. `"@newstate"`.
2. Use a shared service to talk and maintain 'state' between the two state controllers. This may be the cleaner solution. Inject a service (e.g. "NetworksDetailsShowState") into both controllers and proxy the service's properties onto scope properties in both controllers and then change the service at will.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I ended up going the nested view route and it worked just fine.